# Comparing multiple numbers to user input, to find closest answer.

Tags: java, comparison

basically I'm new to java and creating a little program. I've done most of it. Basically I now have four int's, as done by a filereader, and a number made through scanner.in. All I have to do now is to compare the four int's to the scanner.in number, and display the closest number to the scanner.in input.

I'm not exactly sure where to start with this, because it's about comparing the results and I've not encountered this before.

Any help appreciated, I just need to know where to start with it, really.

Cheers guys.

Comment: Is the input in the array, and if it is, is it sorted?

Comment: Nope, it's not in an array. I haven't used an array, though in trying to figure out how to do this, an array seems the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Create another `int` called `closestAnswer`, or something similar. This will be the result you return at the end. By default, `closestAnswer` will get initialized to the first `int` (`guess1`). If the difference between `guess2` and `actualAnswer` is less than the difference between `closestAnswer` and `actualAnswer`, `guess2` becomes the new `closestAnswer`. Then repeat the steps for `guess3` and `guess4`. At the end, `closestAnswer` will represent which of the guesses was closest to `actualAnswer`.

Comment: Also sort the guess[1..4] value so you can use Binary search too.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to finding the smallest number in an array, only you're finding the smallest difference in a set of numbers.

If your 4 numbers are in some sort of list/array/iterable collection, you can step through the number quickly with a for loop.

It might look something like this

```
int currentClosest = numbers[0];
int smallestDifference = Math.Abs(scannedNum - number[0]); //or other infinity-value
for(int i = 1; i < number.length; i++) //iterate through array
{
    int currentDifference = Math.Abs(scannedNum - number[i]);
    if (  currentDifference < smallestDifference) //If this element is closer do stuff
    {
        currentClosest = number[i];
        smallestDifference = currentDifference;
    }
}

//print currentClosest
```

If your numbers aren't in an array or anything like that, you can either put them into one, or just manually code 4 comparisons with similar logic.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could do this, but I would choose a little while-loop

```
int lowerBound = input, upperBound = input;
```

Now arrayOfNumbers should be an ArrayList, so it can use the contains method. You can use an array too, but then you'll have to iterate through yourself, and it just adds unnecessary hassle.

```
while (!arrayOfNumbers.contains(lowerBound) && !arrayOfNumbers.contains(upperBound) {
    lowerBound--;
    upperBound++;
}

// I'm using two 'if's, because there can be two closest
// numbers, if the input is directly between two values.

if (arrayOfNumbers.contains(lowerBound)) {
    System.out.println(lowerBound);
}
if (arrayOfNumbers.contains(upperBound)) {
    System.out.println(upperBound);
}
```

So essentially, it searches upward and downward to find the closest number. It's even easier if you don't use negatives, but I figured I'd be better safe than sorry. And if you're using decimals...well...that's a different story too.